# IF comparison test by value failure ( C++ )

Tags: c++, object

My current project would be too lengthy to post here, however, this is the single line that produces a really strange behavior, at least as I see it . I use the `clip` object to store relatively short strings ( maximum size in use in 35 ), however the condition fails when dealing with negative values in `start` .

I tried adding `(const int)` in front of  `clip.length()`, but the output wouldn't change :

Any ideas what does this mean  ? I'm using G++ on Ubuntu 14.04 .

```
 void Cut ( const int start, const int stop )
 { if (start > clip.length() ) cout << "start: " << start << " > " << clip.length() << endl;

  ...
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Adding a `(const int)` should fix the problem.  Lacking a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, we can't help you.

Comment: Why the downvote ? Please free to suggest how I may improve my post, thank you .

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn you about comparing signed and unsigned integers? You need to enable more warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is this comparison:

```
if (start > clip.length()) {
```

You are comparing a signed and an unsigned here. I suggest changing both operands to have the same type, e.g.:

```
if (start > static_cast<int>(clip.length())) {
```

Additional, the original code produces a nice compiler warning when warnings are turned on (and they **should** be turned on to avoid such issues):

```
test.cpp:8:13: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

With g++, try using `-Wall` and maybe even `-Wextra`.

Comment: I'm quite new to programming and I've been blatantly avoiding warnings, to be honest, but I've learned my lesson now after looking for bugs for 3 hours or so because I didn't enable the warnings .

Comment: This is the deeper answer.  If compiler warnings had been turned on, OP likely would have caught the error before even posting.

Answer (score 12):

It is likely that `length()` returns `unsigned int`, so another argument, `signed int`, gets converted to unsigned too, and then comparison takes place.

It is a part of so called *usual arithmetic conversions*. See the standard:

> **Expressions [expr]**
>
> ....
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
> rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
> the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

Comment: @user43389 If you liked this answer, why don't you accept it?